# comparing data of textbox with database and update database with the new value

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

i am trying to compare the value of textbox with the data in database, and if the value in textbox is bigger den the value of data in database, a alert message will appear and if it is smaller than the value of the data in the datebase, it will minus the database value with the value of textbox and update the value of database. there is no error but when i click on the button, nothing appear and no changes have made to the database. is there anything wrong with my code? thx

```
protected void btn_buy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    hookUp = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\SqlExpress;Database=VoteNow;" +
    "Integrated Security=True" );
    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  UnitAvailable  FROM stockdetails1 WHERE StockID = 3", hookUp);
    hookUp.Open();
    reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    int amountkey;
    amountkey = Convert.ToInt32(amount.Text);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int unitavailable = reader.GetInt32(0);
        int unitavailable1;
        if (amountkey <= unitavailable)
        {
           unitavailable1 = unitavailable - amountkey;
            SqlCommand sqlupdateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockDetails Set UnitAvailable = '+unitavailable1+' WHERE StockID = 3", hookUp);

            sqlupdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> alert('The units available is enough.')</script>"); 
        }
        else 
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> alert('The units available is not enough.')</script>");

        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    hookUp.Close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `sqlupdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after your update command.
Also, I don't understand Why you are alerting the same message again in `else` block of code? The other thing is, probably `UnitAvailable` is a single value so instead of using `ExecuteReader` use `ExecuteScalar`.

Also, consider implementing your code with `using` which will dispose the expensive resources such as connection and command objects.Please check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx) for more.

Your Javascript alert shoul look like:-

```
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('The units available is not enough.')</script>");
```

**Update 2:**

Please use `ExecuteScalar` as i mentioned above like this:-

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  UnitAvailable  FROM StockDetails WHERE StockID = 3", hookUp);
hookUp.Open();
int unitavailable = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
int amountkey;
amountkey = Convert.ToInt32(amount.Text);
int unitavailable1;
if (amountkey <= unitavailable)
{
    Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> alert('The units available is not enough.')</script>");
}
else
{
     unitavailable1 = unitavailable - amountkey;
     SqlCommand sqlupdateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockDetails Set UnitAvailable = @unitavailable1 WHERE StockID = 3", hookUp);
     sqlupdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@unitavailable1",SqlDbType.Int).Value = unitavailable1;
     sqlupdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: ah...wrong message for the else... but if the value of textbox is bigger than the value of data in database, it should have the message appear, but it is not working too

Comment: @benmah - Have you debugged the code? It is actually going to that else block? Also, have updated the correct alert box syntax.

Comment: yup, i removed the message for else, but the code did not work either. no changes have been done to the database. or is it the part where i pass data from database has some problems?

Comment: @benmah - You are the best person to answer that! Put a breakpoint and debug and see if you are getting correct values from DB and if your else block is actually getting executed.

Comment: the alert message is working ald now but when i add the sqlupdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() after the update statement, when i debug an error came out, it says that There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command. which should i close 1st?

Comment: @benmah - Because you have a open dataReader object running, please update your code as i have mentioned in Update 2.

Comment: edited code is updated..thx..just now i tried both alert messages are working fine now. just the updating is not working, even if i delete the alert message code, it is still the same

Comment: @benmah - So have you debugged now? Because now that earlier message must be gone! Please investigate, also while adding parameter I have considered your datatype of `unitavailable1` is int, please check and change accordingly.

Comment: ya...unitavailable1 is int and the unitavailable which is from the database is int too. is it int cant be updated to the database? have to change to string?

Comment: @benmah - Nope, It'll work. Have you debugged the code? Please check what is the error and how it is behaving.

Comment: the error that i am having now is : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.  this is the only error that i have now thx

Comment: @benmah - How come? Why you are still using reader? I have updated the code to use `ExecuteReader` in Update 2, please try with that and remove reader code completely.

Comment: thx man...its working ald...sorry for being such a dumb..haha... not very familiar with asp.net thx

Comment: @benmah - No Prob :) Just read MSDN documentations properly. PS: Do accept it as answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope u have to make two changes to the code.

1. U should add ExecuteNonQuery after the update statement.
2. Also the variable unitavailable1, which is the new available unit had been provided within the quotes..so probably the value is not substituted. Try to close the quotes before that and open it after the variable and use '+' to concatenate them like this

"UPDATE StockDetails Set UnitAvailable = "+unitavailable1+" WHERE StockID = 3".

Try this...Hope this will work...

Comment: after i add the execute non query to the code the error appear and said that There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command.  which must be closed first?